# Register new user in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Web API. I am trying to implement Token authentication in my API. For which I have created the Web API 2 project and a console app for testing my service.

1. Register new time users
2. Authenticate registered users and generate token
3. Client uses the generated token for subsequent requests until token expiry

Below is the code which hits my API.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Task t = new Program().Register("user@domain.com", "Abc123!", "Abc123!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public async Task Register(string username, string password, string confirmPassword)
    {
        RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel
        {
            ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword,
            Password = password,
            UserName = username
        };

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:61086/api/Account/Register");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            await request.GetResponseAsync();
            //return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return false;
        }
        //return request.GetResponseAsync() as Task<WebResponse>;
    }
}

class RegisterModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I get result as 'waitingforactivation'. Can you tell me if I am doing it wrong or suggest a better approach?
Please let me know if I could improve my answer.

Comment: 'waitingforactivation' is a one of the status of Task, way you are calling the aync method is causing the problem.two possible things which you can do either don't create a async method in console application do a .Result on the streamasync method or use something like Postman to test your endpoint.

Comment: @Prashant Thanks for your reply! Now I am able to get 'RanToCompletion' but I have another issue. I get Result = "StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error'. Can you tell me what might be the cause and how I could resolve this?

Comment: internal server error is when your API failed.. you can put a break point in your API and see whats going on.

Comment: @Prashant I put break points in my API in api/Account/Register. This method returns async Task<IHttpActionResult> but my breakpoint does not hit there. However I am able to call the GET and POST methods in my API. I am basically trying to implement Token based authentication. For which, I have to provide an option for the client to register as a new user.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the "WaitingForActivation" result because you are creating an asynchronous HTTP request but you are making it synchronously without waiting for the request to complete.

When you call the `Register()` method you are getting a Task back that represents the continuation of the `Register()` method rather than the method itself.

The "WaitingForActivation" status on the task means that the work within `Register()` has yet to finish so the returned task hasn't been activated yet.

If you wait for `Task t` to complete then you should have the expected response rather than "WaitingForActivation".

```
Task t = new Program().Register("user@domain.com", "Abc123!", "Abc123!");
t.Wait(); // Wait for the task to complete
Console.ReadKey();
```

Take a look at [async/await documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now I am able to get 'RanToCompletion' but I have another issue. Result = "StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error'. Can you tell me what might be the cause and how I could resolve this?

Comment: 500: Internal Server Error could be any number of things, basically something with your HTTP call is failing but it's impossible to know what without debugging it. Try calling your webservice (http://localhost:61086/api/Account/Register) using a tool like Fiddler or Postman to troubleshoot issues with that.

Comment: I did some debugging and found that I am getting an exception- 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server'. I tried changing the DefaultConnection and used my custom connection string for an SQL Server then it is failing inside GrantResourceOwnerCredentials() in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs. The reason being it is trying to find the userID from OAuth user manager which returns null as the user ID is still not registered. Now, I am not sure why it hits this function even though I am posting the data for first time registration.